# Java Spring Thymeleaf DataTable not working

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, dandelion

I want to use dandelion datatables with thymeleaf.My html file is below:

```
<table id="myTableId"
     dt:table="true"
    dt:url="@{/dataTable}"
    dt:serverside="true"
    dt:processing="true"
    dt:deferLoading="10">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th dt:property="id">Id</th>
            <th dt:property="name" dt:default="My default value !">name</th>
            <th dt:property="state">state</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/dataTable")
public @ResponseBody DatatablesResponse<ApplicationItem>  allAppForTable(@DatatablesParams DatatablesCriterias criterias){

    List<Application>  appList=service.listApplications();
    List<ApplicationItem>  aa=new ArrayList<>();

    for(Application a:appList){

        ApplicationItem ai= new ApplicationItem();
        ai.setId(a.getId());
        ai.setName(a.getName());
        ai.setState(a.getState());
        aa.add(ai);
    }
    Long count=(long)appList.size();
    DataSet<ApplicationItem> dataSet=new DataSet<ApplicationItem>(aa, count,null);


    return DatatablesResponse.build(dataSet, criterias);
}
```

But when I enter this page ,table is empty.How can I initialize table when it loading first time.

Comment: Could you post your controller's code?

Comment: Have you considered using DataTables without dandelion?  At least that way is there is an error, DataTables throws an alert,

Comment: Possible, you didn't register dandelion dialect in SpringTemplateEngine bean

Comment: my project is spring4 but the last version of datatables is spring3.Could this be the cause of failure.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://dandelion.github.io/components/datatables/1.1.0/docs/html/#8-4-5-deferring-data-loading) `dt:deferLoadgin` attribute:

> ... allows you to instruct DataTables to not make that initial request, rather it will use the data already on the page (no sorting etc will be applied to it).

Try to remove `dt:deferLoading="10"` attribute from deffinition of `table`.